# Getting gherking.lexer.lexingError, when I try to use javascript in Karate

Tags: javascript, cucumber, karate

### JavascriptUtil.feature

```
Feature: test soap end point

Background: 

* def randomString = function(){ 
                return Math.floor(100000000 + Math.random() * 900000000);}
```

*** Scenario:

### TestFeature file

```
@smoke@sanity
Feature: test soap end poin

Background: 
   * url    'URL of the API'

   * call read('JavascriptUtil.feature')

Scenario:   Test

 * def temp = randomPhoneString()
 * print temp
```

The error I got is:

> Caused by: gherkin.lexer.LexingError: Lexing error on line 6: 'return Math.floor(100000000 + Math.random() * 900000000);}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the line feed please or use the `"""` "doc_string" syntax - [refer documentation](https://github.com/intuit/karate#multi-line-expressions).

```
* def randomString = function(){ return Math.floor(100000000 + Math.random() * 900000000) }
```